# Import a rdf file into neo4j

Tags: neo4j, rdf, jomsocial

I'm currently working on a project which necessits to import into Neo4j datas from website created with Joomla/jomsocial.

I use triplify to generate a rdf file containing some triples.
Triples are on the following form :
<> <> <> .
You can visualize the file [here](http://theprecursor.voila.net/rdf.txt)

I would like to import directly this file.
I guess it's possible because this file describes the graph.

Comment: If you want your app to be performant and you're using semantic technologies, you should use a *real* RDF database.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show the file structure as an example.

Also do you know how your result graph should look like?

In general it is just parsing the file and calling cypher create statements for the nodes and relationships, see: http://neo4j.org/develop/import and http://jexp.de/blog/2013/05/on-importing-data-in-neo4j-blog-series/

For real RDF files there are also importers on top of Neo4j: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/linked_data

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the file structure, my goal is to create a real RDF file (maybe some attributes names will be wrong but nevermind).
I would like to import a file which has the same structure than the file we can find at [this site](http://data.linkededucation.org/ns/linked-education.rdf#body) (rdf dump).

The beginning of the extracted file (14Go) is the following :

```
< http: //dblp.l3s.de/d2r/resource/collections/acm/kim95> < http: //www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> < http: //dblp.l3s.de/d2r/resource/publications/books/acm/Kim95> .

< http: //dblp.l3s.de/d2r/resource/collections/acm/kim95> < http: //purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> "Modern Database Systems"^^< http: //www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
```

I'm gonna try to make a parser but I'm sure a converter `rdf->cypher` or an importer rdf for neo4j already exists.
(or tomorrow, it will)

Comment: If you can find one that suits your needs starting form  http://www.neo4j.org/develop/linked_data fine, otherwise, feel free to do one and notify the list etc. It's OSS after all :)